# My gpcc can not input account and password,greenplum is normal

Tags: greenplum

it say greenplum database is down.contact database administrater to start it,command center

i see gpsmon.log:

> [INTERNAL ERROR gpsmon.c:2124] unable to bind udp socket
>           error 98 (Address already in use)

[hi,i cant input account password,but my gp and gpcc is all running.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDsUW.png)

Comment: can you verify GPDB is up and running by logging in to the db and doing select from gp_segment_configuration? also can you check $MASTER_DATA_DIRECTORY/gpperfmon/logs and check if the gpsmon process log has any errors? You can also confirm the gpsmon and gpmmon processes are running using ps -ef | grep

Comment: gpsmon log is :2016-01-26 18:32:17|:-LOG: HOSTNAME = 'hlg-2p195-yuanfeng'
2016-01-26 18:32:17|:-FATAL: [INTERNAL ERROR gpsmon.c:2124] unable to bind udp socket
 error 98 (Address already in use)
 ... exiting
i see socket 8888 is binding on ipv6 ex::::8888 but not 0.0.0.0:8888

Comment: This looks like there is another process running and occupying this port. Please follow the advise from @IvanNovick and see if there is another process running, and if the gpsmon and gpmmon processes are already running.